# Tkinter Label image setting won´t work

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, label

I've been learning how to use Tkinter from scratch and while I try to set a simple Label widget in a frame:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Practice")

mainW = LabelFrame(root, text = "Main info")
mainW.grid()

image = Label(mainW, image = "C:\Users\Oscar Ramirez\Pictures\image.png")
image.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

codeEntry = Entry(mainW, text = "User Code")
codeEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tutorial.py", line 10, in <module>
    image = Label(mainW, image = "C:\Users\Oscar Ramirez\Pictures\image.png")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 757, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::label", kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 555, in __init__
Tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2096, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image specification must contain an odd number of elements
```

I've checked the image format, the route, etc. And now I don't really know what can be causing me trouble.

Answer (score 5):

> *image*
>   The image to display in the widget. ***The value should be a
>   PhotoImage, BitmapImage, or a compatible object.*** If specified, this
>   takes precedence over the text and bitmap options. (image/Image)

Right now you are just passing a string for image option of [label](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm). You need something like,

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")
label = Label(..., image=photo)
label.photo = photo  #reference keeping is important when working with images
```

Right now, since you are using PNG image, you need to install and use [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) though. For more info, you can read [Photo Image](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) section from effbot.

Comment: Actually, TKinter **does** support PNG files natively

Comment: Since Tkinter 8.6.